# Changing line break patterns

Tags: line-breaking, xepersian

I want to inform latex that it is Ok to break lines at ZWNJ (U+200C) characters, if needed. How can I change the line break patterns (hyphenation) to allow that?

\hyphenation does not work for me and gives error "Not a letter..." when its input contains a ZWNJ.

Example (Compile with xelatex):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\begin{document}
شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a minimum working example showing how you are using this character?

Comment: You won't see it, but, e.g., the word شخصی‌سازی‌شده has two ZWNJ after شخصی and سازی which prevent the word from being seen as شخصیسازیشده.

Comment: I am asking that you edit your question and add a working, compiling LaTeX example.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Why not like this  شخصی‌\-سازی‌شده  ?

Comment: It is used in many places. Also, it is used in other words too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the hyphenation error by assigning an `\lccode` different from 0 to the char.

Something like this could then work (but as I can't read the script ...):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[HyphenChar="200B]{XB Niloofar} %don't show hyphenchar
\lccode`^^^^200c=`^^^^200c
\hyphenation{شخصی-‌-سازی-‌-شده}

\begin{document}

شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده


\end{document}
```

You could also set the ZWJN as the hyphenchar:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[HyphenChar="200C]{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}

شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To allow linebreaks at ZWNJ, you can add discretionaries there, so instead of a "pure" WNJ, you can enter `\discretionary{}{}{^^^^200c}` to allow linebreaks. Now of couse rewriting your entire document would be a lot of work, so you can tell XeTeX to always insert this sequence when it encounters a ZWNJ by making ZWNJ active and assign `\discretionary{}{}{^^^^200c}` as it's replacement. The `newunicodechar` package makes this easy:

```
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\settextfont{Shabnam.ttf}
\newunicodechar{^^^^200c}{\discretionary{}{}{^^^^200c}}
\begin{document}
\showthe\hyphenchar\font
شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده شخصی‌سازی‌شده
\end{document}
```

[image]
(This assumes that you want TeX to avoid breaking there if it is not necessary (like with hyphenation) but you do not want to insert hyphens.)

Comment: It produced many errors. It seems that there is some problem with it when ZWNJ is used inside another command. e.g., ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\protect
l.6 ...و به اصطلاح موتورهای جستجوی \gls{شخصی‌سازی}
شده بیافتند.

Comment: @Shayan well using such a char in the argument of e.g. \gls is simply wrong. The argument of \gls is a *key*, it shouldn't contain arbitrary typesetting.

Comment: If non-english characters like س ش خ can be used in gls, why shouldn't another non-english character can be used in it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your fonts, so I demonstrate with another unicode character what I have in mind.

I use my new `tokcycle` package that was just released yesterday: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle.  In a problem like this, you can think of the package as a glorified stream editor that works with LaTeX tokens.

Here, I search each successive token in the stream.  If it matches the specified unicode character (here `⁊`), it places something different in the output stream.  In the first case, it places `(Hi Mom)` in the output stream.  In the second case, it places a `\-` in the output stream, which is a discretionary hyphen.

And, as you will note, `tokcycle` can properly process spaces, macros, and groups, as well, even working across section boundaries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,tokcycle}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\begin{document}
\Characterdirective{\ifx⁊#1\addcytoks{(Hi Mom)}\else\addcytoks{#1}\fi}
\tokencyclexpress vi⁊-a-viz\endtokencyclexpress

\Characterdirective{\ifx⁊#1\addcytoks{\-}\else\addcytoks{#1}\fi}
\tokencyclexpress xxxxx vi⁊antium vi⁊antium vi⁊antium vi⁊antium vi⁊antium vi⁊antium 
vi⁊antium vi⁊antium vi⁊antium vi⁊antium vi⁊antium

\section{Works across section boundaries!!}

Blah blah blah\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I converted ⁊ to ZWNJ it gave me many errors, e.g., ! Undefined control sequence.
\@chrT #1->\ifx‌
#1\addcytoks {(Hi Mom)}\else \addcytoks {#1}\fi
l.76 \pagenumbering{adadi}

Comment: @Shayan That is because you do not have the `tokcycle` package installed.  If you go to the referenced site and copy the `tokcycle.sty` and `tokcycle.tex` files into your working directory, that should work.

Comment: I upgraded my texlive and installed it from tlmgr. It works with ⁊. But produced errors with ZWNJ.

Comment: @Shayan Not sure what the error might mean.  Perhaps change the `\Characterdirective` to `\Characterdirective{\ifx⁊#1\addcytoks{#1\-}\else\addcytoks{#1}\fi}` (I added `#1` prior to `\-`).  This will print out the character before allowing a discretionary hyphen.

Comment: Again it worked with ⁊ but produced errors with ZWNJ.

Comment: It seems to me that \ifx‌#1 is incompatible with ZWNJ.

Comment: @Shayan Thanks for that information.  Let me think some more on an alternative.

Comment: It seems that the behavior is not limited to ZWNJ. When I replaced ⁊ with س it also produced errors.

Comment: @Shayan I wish I had more experience with/access to such LaTeX fonts.

Comment: That's not related to fonts. They are characters used in Persian. Use the sample code I provided and replace the font with whatever it does not produce an error.

Comment: @Shayan While I can't see the results without the font, I can get it to run (and see an empty box for each Persian letter.  This Character directive compiles and gives a result that includes text substitution: `\Characterdirective{\ifx ی#1\addcytoks{(Hi Mom)}\else\addcytoks{#1}\fi}`.  So it is not a problem with `\ifx`.

Comment: It was compiled for me too. But it seems that the pattern you mentioned never happens because you put a space before ی. If you remove the space errors will probably show up. Also, you can download XB Niloofar here: http://dl.irmug.com/dl.php?id=3